# Calculate center coordinate of Subview on a circle in a UIView (inverted coordinate system)

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, uiview, geometry

I'd like to position the center of a UIButton/UIView (red dot) on the border of a imaginary circle as Subview of another UIView – This means the coordinate system is inverted.

[image]

How do I calculate the CGPoint for the red box center on the circle. Here is what I have …

- (CGPoint) circleCenter x,y
- (float) circleRadius r
- (float) angleAsRadian ⍺

here's what I am trying (thanks @rmaddy)

```
CGFloat buttonX = circleCenter.x + cos(angleAsRadian) * radius;
CGFloat buttonY = circleCenter.y - sin(angleAsRadian) * radius;

CGPoint buttonCenter = CGPointMake(buttonX, buttonY);

UIButton* buttonMarker = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 20, 20)];
[buttonMarker addTarget:self action:@selector(showTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttonMarker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[buttonMarker setCenter:buttonCenter];
[_view addSubview:buttonMarker];
```

... and the current result:

[image]

I am actually expecting the green buttons them to be positioned on top of the pink circles. So not quite there, yet.

Values:

- Radian 10.995574
- Radian 12.042772

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the x and y of the center in general? Is it just the inversion of the `UIView` y-coordinate that is throwing you off? Post what you have done so far to solve this.

Comment: yes, as mentioned I have the circle center coordinates, the radius and the angle. What I am missing is the circle math part considering the inverted coordinate system.

Comment: But I'm asking if you know how to do the math ignoring the inverted coordinate system? If you do, post what you have tried so far. It will be far easier to show you what to fix.

Comment: A circle has 2pi radians. Why are your values so big? The results looks mirrored. Try subtracting X and adding Y instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Import `<math.h>` and do:

```
CGPoint circle = ... // the center of the circle
CGFloat angle = ... // the angle in radians
CGFloat radius = ...// the radius

CGFloat buttonX = circle.x + cos(angle) * radius;
CGFloat buttonY = circle.y - sin(angle) * radius;

CGPoint buttonCenter = CGPointMake(buttonX, buttonY);
```

If you have the angle in degrees you need to convert it to radians.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. I tried that. Still not quite working as expected. See my updated results. Also your buttonCenter should be a CGPoint.